# ViewController Class protocols not loading

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, code-completion

I need to add some protocols to my ViewController class but something goes wrong when I'm typing the name of the protocol, it seems that I'm not able to find that protocol in the list.
But if I start a new project, I'm able to do that.
Is that a bug with Xcode or I'm just doing something wrong?

[image]
Only few protocols are available and I'm not able to find the UIPickerView

[image]
When starting a new project I'm able to find the protocol UIPickerView in the list.

Comment: Did you try to restart your xCode and check this again?

Comment: I have just tried with no luck. ;-(

Comment: I think there is a bug in your project.another way is to create new project and start every thing again.. :)

Comment: It's the 4th time I'm starting everything again for bugs like this.... I can't believe it.........

Comment: Xcode has been doing this for me on and off with no rhyme or reason. Buggy!

Comment: What happens after you full type the name of the protocol manually? Does Xcode complain any topics within your code? The error may not be related to the current line.